# add it to Localstorage so that it does not delete the recorded information when I go to and from the next page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, local-storage, uitextfield

How do I add it to Localstorage so that it does not delete the recorded information when I go to and from the next page?
full code

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [lastname, setLastname] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
<Box sx={{ ml: "140px", mb: "30px" }}>
    {multipleInput.map((item) => {
      return (
        <Grid item sm={8}>
          <TextField
            sx={{ mt: "20px" }}
            autoComplete={item.autoComplete}
            fullWidth
            value={item.value}
            onChange={(e) => item.setValue(e.target.value)}
            label={item.label}
            InputLabelProps={{ style: { fontFamily: "Montserrat" } }}
            inputRef={item.inputRef}
            type={item.type}
          />
        </Grid>
      );
    })}
  </Box></Box>
  <Link href="TechSkill">
    <Button>
      <NavigateNextIcon />
    </Button>
  </Link>
```

Comment: the values in multipleInput are coming from an API or from localStorage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to save the value of a variable to localStorage, and it's easy enough to do.

You can use the `useEffect` hook, which will monitor the update of the variable and constantly update the localStorage.

**Saving** looks like this:

```js
// SAVING
useEffect(() => {
  // storing input name
  localStorage.setItem("phone", JSON.stringify(phone));
}, [phone]);
```

So, when a user will update the value of variable phone, the value in localStorage will be updated automatically.

To **read** the value from the localStorage, do the following:

```js
// READING
const [phone, setPhone] = useState(() => {
  // getting stored value
  const saved = localStorage.getItem("phone");
  const initialValue = JSON.parse(saved);
  return initialValue || "";
});
```

But for exact answer it's not clear what exactly you want to do, in general the variant described above should work if you tweak it.

Comment: I have several pages and at the end I have to send all the data, it is also necessary that these fields are unchanged when returning, until the user clicks submit

Comment: You can safely save any data to localStorage, for example you can save data from `page1` like this `localStorage.setItem("page1", JSON.stringify(page1Data));` Don't forget to accept answer if it was helpful.